# Sonata Admin custom route for one admin -without prefix

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

i have this code

```
admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_security:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_resetting:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml'
    prefix: /admin
```

so all admins have prefix /

i realy need add allow access for other users not admins for one admin.
Is possible to create route without prefix for one admin ?